# NserviceBus - Removing properties from SagaData entities

Tags: nservicebus

I have a SagaData class which has a lot of redundant properties which I would like to remove during our next release. However there are ongoing Sagas active on Production right now, and I'm not sure what effect removing those properties on the SagaData class will have on the already existing Sagas.

Afaik NServiceBus handles creating db tables for us, one of which has all those redundant properties as columns. Can anyone point me in the direction of learning what will happen if those properties are removed from the SagaData class. Assume that the properties aren't being used, only populated and code will be refactored accordingly. - I'm wondering what will happen to our db, and what will happen to the existing Sagas

Thanks

Comment: Can you add information about the persister and versions of the persister you are using so that we can better help you? Based on your description I would assume it is the NHibernate persister but I want to double check

Comment: Yes it's NHibernate, version is 4.0.1 and NServiceBus version 5.2.14 - Might be time to upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### NHibernate schema updates

NHibernate only does schema additions and only when the NH schema generator is run via the NServiceBus NHibernate installers (`.EnableInstallers()`). NHibernate doesn't do schema migrations like column type changes, column renames, and column deletions. This is a limitation by NHibernate, not by NServiceBus.

### Scripting SQL

Breaking schema changes all need to be scripted manually. You can use a tool to run your manually created scripts [RoundhousE](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse) or many other similar tools. You can also diff databases using a tool like Microsoft Database Deployment Projects (SSDT), which can create these scripts for you.

### Removing columns

If you have a new saga, you can just wait until all old sagas completed as @hadi mentioned, you can even then remove that old table when unused.

### Modifying existing saga

If you modify the existing saga this means your implementation will not be using these columns anymore at all, also for existing saga instances. You can safely remove these columns from the table(s) after deploying your new version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything will happen to your database. You'll have to remove the redundant columns via a migration. NServiceBus won't do that for you.

You can deploy a new version of your endpoints to production, let the old/existing sagas complete over time and then decommission the old endpoint and remove the unnecessary columns.

Have a look [here](https://docs.particular.net/samples/saga/migration/) for a sample that explains saga migration in details.

Comment: Not sure why you share the migration sample, that is how to migrate to a different persistence without downtime.

Comment: The point was to show that this can be done by 'versioning' the saga and dropping the table later.